# How do I check if there are any duplicates in a row in a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to display an error message if there are any duplicates in the first column of a matrix (for example the one below).

```
np.array([[s1,2,4,7],
          [s2,7,10,12],
          [s1,2,-3,4]])
```

Comment: You could test `np.unique(a[:,0]).shape == a[:,0].shape` also your question title contradicts your question in the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare whether the shape of the output from [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) on the first column is the same on the original column:

```
In [301]:
np.unique(a[:,0]).shape == a[:,0].shape

Out[301]:
False
```

Here `np.unique` returns the unique values:

```
In [302]:
np.unique(a[:,0])

Out[302]:
array(['s1', 's2'], 
      dtype='<U2')
```

So if `False` you can then display your error message